# DataTable API, Laravel: why the datatable api is not working and dont give any errors back?There is another way to filter colmns

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to build a filter to my columns 'vendedor', 'cliente' and 'data' :

```
@csrf
 <h2>Orcamento</h2>
  
  <table id="example" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th  scope="col">Vendedor</th>
      <th  scope="col">Cliente</th>
      <th  scope="col">Data</th>
      <th  scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th   scope="col">
      <a href="{{url('orcamentos/create')}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mb-2"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adicionar </button>
      </a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

And I try all the pressets from the datatable but they do nothing:

```
@section('javascripts')

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
@endsection
```

this is the final part of the document, im almost sure this is correct, but is my first time using datatables and laravel, if you know other way to do the filter the comments are open:

```
  <tbody>
  
  
  @foreach($orcamento as $object)
    <tr>
      <td data-column="0">{{$object->vendedor}}</td>
      <td data-column="1">{{$object->cliente}}</td>
      <td data-column="2">{{$object->created_at}}</td>
      <td data-column="2">{{$object->valor}}</td>
      <td>
      <a href="{{url("orcamentos/$object->id")}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="margin-left: 3px;"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Visualizar</button>
      </a>
      <a href="{{url("orcamentos/$object->id/edit")}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="margin-left: 3px;"> <i class="fas fa-pen"></i> Editar</button>
      </a>
      <a href="{{url("orcamentos/$object->id")}}" class="js-del">
        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-3">Deletar <i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i></button>
      </a>
      </td>
    
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
 
 
  <tfoot> 
    <tr>
      <th  scope="col">Vendedor</span></th>
      <th  scope="col">Cliente</span></th>
      <th  scope="col">Data </span></th>
      <th  scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th style="margin-top: 20px;" scope="col">{!!$orcamento->links() !!}</th>
    </tr>
    
  </tfoot>
 
</table>
```

Comment: Do you check your browser console?

Comment: doesnt return me any errors

Comment: I have never used DataTable before, but your HTML isn't valid, maybe that's messing it up? You can't have an `<hN>` tag or a `<br />` tag as a child of `<table>`.

Comment: like this? `<h2 class="text-center font-weight-bold mb-4">Orçamentos</h2>
@csrf
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" id="datatable">
  <tr>
    <td>`